# Flutter exits unexpectedly with error using Linux Mint

Tags: linux, flutter, crash, linux-mint

Newly installed Flutter. When trying to run flutter doctor or creating a new project with Android Studio (plugin and dart installed), Flutter exits unexpectedly. Flutter folder/install is in /opt and path was added to .profile. Would it be better to install/move flutter to a user location? Android Studio is in /opt.

```
FileSystemException: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/opt/flutter/bin/cache/lockfile'
(OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
```

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux

Answer (score 1):

Resolved with permissions update (also moved to home directory prior to permissions change).